# Can you alias a scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, alias, named-scopes

Say I have this scope:

```
scope :with_zipcode, lambda { |zip| where(zipcode: zip) }
```

and I want an equivalent scope

```
scope :has_zipcode, lambda { |zip| where(zipcode: zip) }
```

is there a way to alias one scope to another? For instance something like

```
alias :with_zipcode, :has_zipcode
```

P.S. I know this is a contrived and unrealistic example, just curious to know if it is possible!

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes you can. Just remember that scopes are class methods so that you need to  alias in the context of the class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_zipcode, lambda { |zip| where(zipcode: zip) }
  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :has_zipcode, :with_zipcode)
end
```

Answer (score 14):

An alternative way to define an alias for a class method which I personally find a bit more self-explanatory:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_zipcode, lambda { |zip| where(zipcode: zip) }

  class << self
    alias has_zipcode with_zipcode
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Another solution is to call one scope from another

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_zipcode, lambda { |zip| where(zipcode: zip) }
  scope :has_zipcode,  lambda { |zip| with_zipcode(zip)   } # essentially an alias
end
```

Using `singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :a, :b)` is probably less ambiguous, but just wanted to alert to another option.